# string_view with a deallocator

Tags: c++, c++17, string-view

I'm trying to use `std::string_view` as much as I can to wrap C-string, however, whenever the C-string I'm wrapping is dynamically allocated, I rely on this pattern:

```
char *cs = get_c_string();
std::string s(cs);
free(cs);
```

which is a waste of time because it involves 1 allocation, 1 copy and 1 deallocation.

Is there a way to do this better ? Or do I need to write my own `string_view` wrapper ?

Comment: How you deal with the ownership of the memory behind a `string_view` is entirely up to you. That's the whole point of the type; the code taking it doesn't care about how it's owned.

Comment: How about managing the string's lifetime using a `unique_ptr` and custom deleter, and create `string_view`s from it as needed? You could wrap this up in some custom type that saves the length of the c-string to avoid having to compute it every time you create a `string_view`.

Comment: _whenever_ also known as seldom.

Comment: @manni66 Do you know what C libraries the OP is using? Maybe it’s not good style, but that doesn’t mean it’s seldom in their codebase.

Answer (score 4):

`string_view` does not have **any** ownership semantics whatsoever. If you want to take ownership of it, use a smart pointer.

```
std::unique_ptr<char, decltype(&std::free)> cs(get_c_string(), std::free);
```

Or:

```
template <auto Deleter>
struct FuncDeleter {
    template <class P>
    void operator()(P* p) const { Deleter(p); }
};

std::unique_ptr<char, FuncDeleter<std::free>> cs(get_c_string());
```

Comment: Can't `std::free`'s type be deduced, since we are talking about [tag:c++1z]?

Comment: @Zereges From what?

Comment: `std::unique_ptr<char, decltype(&std::free)> cs(get_c_string(), std::free);` into `std::unique_ptr<char> cs(get_c_string(), std::free);` or even `std::unique_ptr cs(get_c_string(), std::free);`

Comment: @Zereges There's no class template argument deduction for `std::unique_ptr`... and even if there were, the first thing you suggest wouldn't work because there's never any partial class template argument deduction.

Comment: It’s difficult to use a `unique_ptr<char*>` as a string in C++. You’d need to at least make a `string_view` as well for it to be usable, and if you wanted to change ownership you’d need to pass both around. Although it would work slightly better if you made it a `unique_ptr<char[], decltype(std::free)>` instead.